# Docker & PostgreSQL performance/errors during big update/migration script

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance

I've been working on coming up with a script to migrate a DB. That process involves updating something like 250k URLs in the database to point to their new address.
With some help from SO, I think I've managed to nail that part...

However, I'm having some trouble with the speed/performance of the script, and while trying to address that, I've ran into an error with PostgreSQL that causes the DB to enter recovery mode.. I should also add that I'm mostly a developer and I don't usually deal directly with DBs and have little experience with PostgreSQL other than being told "that's the DB, read/write there" so it's quite possible I'm doing this wrong.

So, let's take this in parts..

I'm running PostgreSQL via docker compose on a Mac. Docker has 16GB of RAM assigned to it and PostgreSQL is the only container running. The database itself, has 570MB of disk used total when ready.

```yaml
  db:
    build:
      context: ./server/local-db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # command: -c fsync=off -c full_page_writes=off -c synchronous_commit=off
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512m
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      # Volume to persist db content even if "docker-compose down" is run. Add "-v" to delete also volumes
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # - /Volumes/ramdisk/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./server/local-db/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./server/local-db/dumps/:/dumps/
```

Among other approaches and earlier attempts, I've tried the following with the respective outcomes:

- Do "nothing" and update in place.. No errors, but this takes horribly long and I've never gotten the process to get to even 1/4 the way within 24 hours.
- Disable FK, Indexes and set tables as unlogged. I don't run into any errors, but like the previous attempt, it takes forever to even get to a 1/4 of the way in 24 hours running, although it *looks* a little bit faster
- I've tried using ramdisk and, somehow, that's even slower than the above options..
- Create unlogged or temp table copies of the target tables. This also is horribly slow.

So, now on my latest version, I've read a bit on the `temp_buffers` and `work_mem` properties, and understanding their impact on the queries, I set them at the very beginning of the script, and the process is A LOT faster. I was happy:

```sql
-- I've already tried 512MB, 2048MB and 4096MB here..
SET temp_buffers = '1024MB';
SET work_mem = '1024MB';

-- ...

  create temp table temp_document_metadata as (
    select * from document_metadata
  );

  create temp table temp_document_revisions as (
    select * from document_revisions
  );
    
  create temp table temp_media_library_entries as (
    select * from media_library_entries
  );

-- Do the rest of the work on these tables
```

While this looked very promising, the problem I'm facing now is that PostgreSQL seems to error, enter `recovery mode` and this will cause the script to fail, and I don't understand why.

```
2023-06-18 15:04:46.322 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.8 (Debian 14.8-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-06-18 15:04:46.322 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-06-18 15:04:46.322 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-06-18 15:04:46.327 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-06-18 15:04:46.332 UTC [119] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-06-18 15:04:46 UTC
2023-06-18 15:04:46.338 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-06-18 15:42:55.830 UTC [1] LOG:  server process (PID 341) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2023-06-18 15:42:55.830 UTC [1] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: -- "Main" update operation
        do
        $$
        declare 
          -- items record;
          storiesIds int[] := array(select id from documents order by id);
          storyId int;
          total_stories int := 0;
          idx int := 0;
        begin
          -- Setup initial data
          perform setup_migration();

          total_stories := array_length(storiesIds, 1);

          -- General updates
          RAISE NOTICE 'Updating media_library_entries metadata and Image Service...';
          perform run_updates_metadata_url();
          perform run_updates_metadata_originalUrl();
          perform run_updates_metadata_media_proxy();

          RAISE NOTICE 'Updating document_revisions URLs per document...';
          RAISE NOTICE 'Total Stories: %', total_stories;
          foreach storyId in array storiesIds
          loop
            idx := idx + 1;
            RAISE NOTICE '% of %: Story: %', idx, total_stories, storyId;
            perform run_updates_url(storyId);
            perform run_updates_originalUrl(storyId);
               
            perform run_updates_url_documents_metadata(storyId);
            perform run_updates_originalUrl_documents_metadata(storyId);
            
          end loop;
          
          perform run_up
2023-06-18 15:42:55.831 UTC [1] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2023-06-18 15:42:55.866 UTC [1] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2023-06-18 15:42:55.984 UTC [6422] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-06-18 15:29:47 UTC
2023-06-18 15:42:55.989 UTC [6423] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
...
2023-06-18 15:42:56.444 UTC [6445] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2023-06-18 15:42:56.453 UTC [6422] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-06-18 15:42:56.465 UTC [6446] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2023-06-18 15:42:56.470 UTC [6422] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1DBA1D58
2023-06-18 15:42:56.470 UTC [6422] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1DBA1E98: wanted 24, got 0
2023-06-18 15:42:56.470 UTC [6422] LOG:  redo done at 0/1DBA1E60 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
2023-06-18 15:42:56.531 UTC [6447] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
...
2023-06-18 15:42:56.663 UTC [6457] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2023-06-18 15:42:56.699 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-06-18 15:43:01.254 UTC [6466] ERROR:  relation "temp_media_library_entries" does not exist at character 8
```

The "funny" thing about it, is that running a shorter version of the script (partially updating the data) will complete in about 1 hour without any sort of help and work beautifully. However, the same is not true with these settings..

Is is Docker killing the process? I don't see any particularly helpful logs and I don't understand why. Where else can I check?

Are the settings I'm placing causing this issue and if so, how/why?
How are the `temp_buffers`/`work_mem` settings affecting the completion of the script since it seems to run (slowly, but still run) with a subset of the data but not when setting these values?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to look at docker's logs rather than PostgreSQL's. Do you see `rver process (PID 341) was terminated by signal 9: Killed` - that's something external killing it, probably because it is out of memory. Your tuning values are probably too big for your setup. That "work_mem" is the amount of memory per sort and a query can do several  together. I just had a look at your posting history and realised you're the chap with the weird jsonified data structures. I don't have time to dig through those to understand the core issues, but.. if you can update a subset just repeat that.

Comment: try to find the cause maybe this will https://medium.com/@pimterry/5-ways-to-debug-an-exploding-docker-container-4f729e2c0aa8